# "Data Source Cannot be Shared" following upgrade to O365

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I recently updated to Office 365 and with it a few of my vba tools fell over, but the majority have been easily fixable. This one is confusing me:

My code uses query tables to get some data from an access database (which is where I suspect this is falling over) and then does some calculations before creating an input file for some external software. I then use shell to run that external software with that newly created input file before fetching and processing the results file for visualisation in Excel. The code is extensive so I won't reproduce reams of code here.

For the DB query I am using the syntax (see below for a longer description of the operation of the code):

> mydatabase.QueryTables.Add(... etc

The window that pops up when I try to run the script is shown below, I used message box flags to prove that this occurs as it tries to look in the access database for the first time.

[image]

This worked perfectly on Excel 2011 before I upgraded to O365. Note that access was also updated at the same time.

**I am self taught and don't know what this means or how to fix it. Can anybody provide any insight?**

How the code works:

In the main body:

```
MsgBox "Starting Query"
gtdatabase.Visible = xlSheetHidden 'hide the worksheet
Create_DBQuery number
MsgBox "Completing Query"
```

I see "Starting Query" but then the "Select Data Source" window, without seeing that my query has been completed. The sub "CreateDBQuery" works as follows (Modified so identifiers are removed):

```
Sub Create_DBQuery(ByVal number As String)
'
With mydatabase.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=MyDept;Description= GT Database;UID=Administrator;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=XXXX111;DATABASE=GTDB;Tr" _
        ), Array("usted_Connection=Yes")), Destination:=mydatabase.Range("A1"))
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT DataSheetSummary.a, DataSheetSummary.b, DataSheetSummary.c, DataSheetSummary.d, DataSheetSummary.e, DataSheetSummary.f, DataSheetSummary.g, DataSheetSummary.h, Data" _
        , _
        "SheetSummary.j, DataSheetSummary.k, DataSheetSummary.l, DataSheetSummary.m, DataSheetSummary.n, DataSheetSummary.p, DataSheetSummary.q, DataSheetSummary.r, DataSheetSummary." _
        , _
        "s, DataSheetSummary.t, DataSheetSummary.u, DataSheetSummary.v, DataSheetSummary.w" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM GT.dbo.DataSheetSummary DataSheetSummary" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (DataSheetSummary.DataSheet_Number Like '" & number & "')" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10))
        .Name = "Query from GT_2"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If the code is extensive, please provide a [mre]. You've provided very little information we can use to actually get to the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Erik, the relevant part is included as far as I can tell. I can add a full (simplified) version of my DB query, but it uses the basic syntax stated above. It falls over at the DB query, everything before this executes without issue. As stated it all works in Excel 2011 and my only clue is that dialogue window.

Comment: Eh, no, the relevant part is not included. Think about this from a readers perspective: Do I know all the things I need to know to get the same error, so I can try to fix it?

Comment: I have modified the entire query that fails in order to remove identifying info and added to the question (along with the location in the main body where it falls over). I figured if somebody knew that pop up window they could provide the insight I needed, apologies.

Comment: Does that DSN you're referring to (_MyDept_) exist? Does it have the same bitness as your Office installation? This is probably just a mismatch between the DSN bitness and the Office application bitness, which often happens when upgrading from 32-bits to 64-bits Office

Comment: The change is bitness makes sense - although I don't know how to rectify this. I wouldn't know how to begin proving that my DNS "exists", other than it works elsewhere, and is listed in my connections within Excel. Apologies for being so helpless, I am not very familiar with SQL/Databases (I'm a mechanical engineer - no computing background!).

Comment: You can easily view DSNs using the ODBC data source administrator panel on the control panel under administrative tools. Here, you can also create a DSN with an identical name and identical settings, provided you knew the settings contained in your previous DSN.

Comment: I do not have administrator access on this network unfortunately, so I am a little screwed until I can get an IT person to come over here and give me access. They know less in this area than even me in my past experience, so I will likely need to find a solution to this myself or rewrite my code to no longer use a DSN, e.g.  https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10063.aspx

Comment: Yup, going DSNless is advisable, certainly if you don't have administrator access but really always. You _can_ create user DSNs without administrative access, though, but I still recommend going DSNless. Good luck, can't help you without knowing details you'd probably like to keep confidential.